# MariaDb is installed but could not be imported into python

Tags: python, installation, mariadb, connector

I tried to install the Mariadb plugin for python. Therefore I downloaded the MariaDB Connector and installed it and then I installed via pip3 the mariadb. And I think it worked:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting mariadb
Using cached mariadb-1.0.6.tar.gz (67 kB)
Installing collected packages: mariadb
Running setup.py install for mariadb ... done
Successfully installed mariadb-1.0.6
```

But when I want to import it:

```
import mariadb
```

I still get the message: No module 'mariadb'

Any ideas what I could to to check/fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're doing that:

When you installed mariadb via pip3 you have to use Python 3 too:

```
    python3 your_file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

pip installs mariadb to a site-packages directory.   On my win10, PYTHONPATH was:
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages

But there are two site-packages.  I appended to PYTHONPATH: ;C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages

Now python imports mariadb OK.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).